# Codesign: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer

Tags: ios, unreal-engine4, codesign

I'm getting some weird errors when trying to package an UE4 iOS app, Codesign return this:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign D7B82F040B126A01B59DAAF4CE968801525B81F4 --entitlements /Users/louga31/UE4/Builds/QOY/D/UE4_Projects/App/Intermediate/ProjectFilesIOS/build/App.build/Shipping-iphoneos/App.build/App.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/louga31/UE4/Builds/QOY/D/UE4_Projects/App/Binaries/IOS/Payload/App.app     
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Distribution (H7N8851C17)"
/Users/louga31/UE4/Builds/QOY/D/UE4_Projects/App/Binaries/IOS/Payload/App.app: errSecInternalComponent
```

I saw some other people asked questions about this problem on Stack Overflow, but none of the provided solutions worked for me.
What I already tried:

- Lock and unlock Key Access
- Trust certificate
- Change private key security to all apps
- Trust Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificate (Both the one expiring in 2023 and the one expiring in 2030)
- Delete all keys and certificates and generate one directly from Xcode

I tried running the same codesign command in the Mac terminal, and it didn't worked.
I managed to make the codesign command work by running it as sudo in the terminal, so I tend to think it's a permission issue somewhere (UE4 doesn't run codesign as sudo, so this doesn't really fix anything)

Comment: Are you building from Xcode? Can you open the Report Navigator (Cmd+9 in Xcode), then click on the latest failed build entry? That's where you'll have your build logs; they will typically tell you exactly what's wrong. Inspect the log for any errors.

Comment: I'm not building through Xcode, I'm building using UE4 through SSH.
I added the full build command and output to the question if it can help you

Comment: I have the same error when connecting through SSH. See my problem description here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690923#690923021. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I posted my fix as a solution, it's dirty, but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my dirty fix for this (I'm sure there are better ways, but this one works).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/louga31/f22a7522d4016ecf46bbd5102ef87c41) is the github patch, you need to apply it on the 4.26 branch. (Not tested in 4.27)

You also need to place the file AppleWWDRCAG3.cer in Engine\Extras (you can get it [here](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer))

This fix also allows you to specify the root certificate you want to use with UnrealBuildTool, in case you need to use a custom one.